# Can not emulate curl request using c# HttpClient

Tags: c#, httpclient

I have a `cURL` `POST` request what creates issue in YouTrack:

```
curl -X POST https://my.youtrack/api/issues \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer perm:123" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d "{\"project\":{\"id\":\"67-74\"},\"summary\":\"REST API lets you create issues!\",\"description\":\"Lets create a new issue using YouTracks REST API.\"}"
```

Now i trying to do the same using c#:

```
public async static Task<string> SendPostRequestAsync(string url, string postParams)
{
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://my.youtrack/") };
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "perm:123");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var content = new StringContent(postParams, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("api/issues", content);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Sending JSON the same `{"description":"Created using REST Api","project":"{\"id\":\"67-74\"}","summary":"Test Issue"}`.

But get `500 Internal Server Error`. Just can't see what a problem here, im sending json incorrectly?

Comment: Do you get a response body back, with more information?

Comment: Wonderful 500's, none of them are actually useful, general catch all issues and could be more specific.

Comment: Ah, wait one second: your JSON is different: you've got ``\`` before some `"`'s, but not others

Comment: When speaking to an HTTP server, the server doesn't know whether you're using CURL or .NET to talk to it. The server only talks in HTTP requests and responses. Therefore, if the server is doing something different, it can only be because the request you're sending it is different. Diff the requests, figure out the difference, and eliminate it.

Comment: The issue is the `json` as @canton7 mentioned. The structure is different for the `c#` version. The API could at least send something meaningful back about this...

Comment: @mason Indeed. It's fairly clear that the point of this question is "Spot the difference between this cURL request and this HttpClient request, because I can't spot it"

Comment: @canton7 In debug modei see this json `"{\"description\":\"Created using REST Api\",\"project\":\"{\\\"id\\\":\\\"67-74\\\"}\",\"summary\":\"Test Issue\"}"` so every quote has \. I miss something here?

Comment: @KliverMax You're missing the fact that some have *three* ``\``'s (in the debug view, which means they have a single ``\`` in your original string)

Comment: @mason Right, and saying "This is easy" (paraphrasing: you've deleted your original comment) doesn't teach anyone anything

Comment: Right, and you've provided on guidance on how to do that. If you'd suggested using Fiddler for example, that would be helpful. Or recommended looking at the JSON specifically, or pointing them at the backslash problem, or... But "Diff it" doesn't tell them anything they didn't already know. Asking well-written questions on this website isn't a crime: in fact it's arguably the point of the site. Questions which are caused by typos can be closed as such, but people are still welcome to help in the comments. SO has a reputation as being very unwelcoming, and this is partly why

Comment: @KliverMax Have you actually compared the HTTP requests to each other? There are tools like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) that can grab the HTTP requests. Once you have them, you can diff them and that will let you pinpoint the problem. When a server is giving different responses to your requests, then the problem must be the requests aren't the same, so the next logical step is to figure out why they're not the same.

Comment: i tried the curl command in ubuntu, why do i get `-bash: !\: event not found`?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the quotes around the object after *project*, if you do the following then the c# json should match the CURL json

instead of this

```
{"description":"Created using REST Api","project":"{\"id\":\"67-74\"}","summary":"Test Issue"}
```

try this

```
{"description":"Created using REST Api","project":{"id":"67-74"},"summary":"Test Issue"}
```

which looks like this in escaped for **string** in c#

```
"{\"description\":\"Created using REST Api\",\"project\":{\"id\":\"67-74\"},\"summary\":\"Test Issue\"}"
```

the original json was passing the object after **project** as a string

Answer (score 0):

> Sending JSON the same {"description":"Created using REST Api","project":"{"id":"67-74"}","summary":"Test Issue"}

Unfortunately, that is not the same as the CURL request as project is originally `\"project\":{\"id\":\"67-74\"}`  - unescaping the quotes gives `"project":{"id":"67-74"}`. You'll notice that project is an object with an `id` property.

Your C# "equivalent" has `"project":"{\"id\":\"67-74\"}"` where project is a string containing `{"id":"67-74"}` not an object at all.

Fix your JSON and it should work as expected.